# Spring Excel Download returning random data in file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Below are the methods I have written to generate excel file and send it as a download option.
but I am getting some junk data as response.
Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/loanaccounts/repaymentScheduleInExcel", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
@Timed
public void  repaymentScheduleInExcel(@RequestParam(value = "accountNumber", required = true) String accountNumber, HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception, URISyntaxException {
    log.debug("REST request to do unmarkNPA");
    loanProcessService.repaymentScheduleInExcel(accountNumber, response);
}
```

Implemenation method:

```
public void repaymentScheduleInExcel(String accountNumber,HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+ accountNumber+ ".xlsx");
        response.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        response.setDateHeader("Last-Modified", System.currentTimeMillis());
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        String file = "D://text.xlsx";
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(file));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("repayment_schedule_details");
        String[] headers = {"Sequence Num","Transaction Name","Demand Date","Transaction Date","Installment Amount","Balance Amount","Interest Due","Principle Due"};
        Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
        for(String header : headers){
            int j = 0;
            Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(j++);
            cell.setCellValue(header);
        }
        LoanOdSummaryWSDto transactionSummary = encoreService.findSummary(accountNumber, true);
        if(transactionSummary != null && transactionSummary.getRepaymentSchedule() != null && transactionSummary.getRepaymentSchedule().size()>0){
            List<TransactionSummaryWSDto> repaymentSchedules = transactionSummary.getRepaymentSchedule();
            for(TransactionSummaryWSDto repaymentSchedule : repaymentSchedules){
                int rowNumber = 1;
                Row valueRow = sheet.createRow(rowNumber++);
                int columnNumber = 0;
                Cell seqNum = valueRow.createCell(columnNumber++);                              
                seqNum.setCellValue(repaymentSchedule.getSequenceNum());
                Cell transactionName   = valueRow.createCell(columnNumber++);                               
                transactionName.setCellValue(repaymentSchedule.getTransactionName());
                Cell valueDate   = valueRow.createCell(columnNumber++);                             
                valueDate.setCellValue(repaymentSchedule.getValueDate());
                Cell transactionDate   = valueRow.createCell(columnNumber++);                               
                transactionDate.setCellValue(repaymentSchedule.getTransactionDate());
                Cell amount   = valueRow.createCell(columnNumber++);                                
                amount.setCellValue(repaymentSchedule.getAmount1());
                Cell amount2   = valueRow.createCell(columnNumber++);                               
                amount2.setCellValue(repaymentSchedule.getAmount2());
                Cell part1   = valueRow.createCell(columnNumber++);                             
                part1.setCellValue(repaymentSchedule.getPart1());
                Cell part2   = valueRow.createCell(columnNumber++);                             
                part2.setCellValue(repaymentSchedule.getPart2());
            }
        }
        workbook.write(f);
        workbook.close();
        System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ProgramException("encore call failure for given account number");
    }
}
```

Output:

PK  3��J               _rels/.rels���J1���Pr���
"�u/"�Md}��ff�L��F���E]w@�c���?H��9L�r�
��E�������nu�F�G2v7�g��P�N|*�Bb10��k��(`i8Q���s@�e�uB;bOzӶ�:e�1U흁�wkP�=��yү��'汩�:xK��X�:o��s�('ҏ^�^��|�8����.���:4EGn�je�T��.N8Y��7����@�?�?����P;�PK�A���   U  PK  3��J               [Content_Types].xml�SMO1���6��m��1���G%@mgن~����cDH0��t�޼�:iG㕳�R6�7l����6~ְ��s}˪��ki����������:B�h��u��N��:p2��҆�$R�f"J5�3׃��P�#x��h����\X�6Ho���%�����;��V�'�='w&�+"��iE*���8�cw����+�'
����(�A-�p(�t�f�Ȅ/ґ� ��,H�����eY�'z��8�R� �幓    �&zXc���E8k\�=�(z�[�ʝ4~��gH���LP<�� =�E_�?ID����PK�c��@  2  PK  3��J               docProps/app.xmlM��
�0D��ro�z�4� �'{����MHV�盓z���T��E�1e�����Ɇ�ѳ����:�No7jH!bb�Y��V��������T�)$o���0M��9ؗGb�7�pe��*~�R�>��Y�EB���nW������ PK6n�!�   �   PK  3��J               docProps/core.xmlm��J�0F�ߡ依�w    �.�,�V�B2���$���M�k�rf�f��������r��F����c�K�$�k���"ڐm}~��  �p�Ez�Iiτ�H�e ^t���"����8�C,]��7�"y~
��ǧ���H��Or&�2�

> mL�{�T^]7;R9]��*�놖�RV/��T+���J����f"�v��Oر�PKq�  �  PK  3��J               xl/sharedStrings.xmlm��J1���Pzw;z�E:]�A��"�>@�dw
>   m:6���vDw��|ɟ?��|��>�p����U

Comment: try `application/vnd.ms-excel` instead of `application/xls` or `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` if it is `xslx`

Comment: Still same issue even after trying to use application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.‌​sheet and the file has type "SHEET-REPAYMNETSCHEDULEINEXCEL.."

Answer (score -1):

I think this is not `application/xls` but rather

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4212908/4899193).

### EDIT

The syntax of the `Content-Disposition` header is incorrect: The filename should be in double quotes.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\""+ accountNumber+ ".xlsx\"");
```

Comment: Still same issue even after trying to use application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.‌​sheet and the file has type "SHEET-REPAYMNETSCHEDULEINEXCEL.."

Comment: Updated the latest code using application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet